# plugin:vite:import-analysis Failed to resolve import "react-dom/client" from "src/main.jsx"

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

I am new to Vite.I was trying to setup my react app using vite when I encountered the error after building the app. I am using React18. Below is my main.jsx file

```
Main.jsx
```

```
    import React from 'react'
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
    import App from './App'
    import './index.css'

    ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
     <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file I needed to fix was `main.jsx`.

Replace the code in `main.jsx` with this variant:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import App from "./App.jsx";

const container = document.getElementById("root");
 render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
 </React.StrictMode>,
  container
);
```

Not a huge amount has changed, but let's review the differences. Firstly, on line two we import the `render` function from `react-dom` instead of importing `ReactDOM` from `react-dom/client`. Secondly, we use that `render` function to render the `App` component rather than using `createRoot` from the new React 18 root API.

The site should now hot reload and we see our page with the counter. If not, restart the server and reload the page.